# existing algorithm for object tracking in low resolution

Tags: algorithm, tracking

I am trying to implement an object tracking algorithm for two four times four pixel opencv matrices. I say opencv, because best case for me would be if there is some already implemented algorithm that could handle the requirements.

The data stems from a low resolution time of flight sensor, that gives me the distance and the singalrate of an object in each pixel. The singalrate can be used as an estimate for how much of the pixel (=region of interest) is occupied by an object (in percent).

I'll best give an example of what the data looks like:
[image: 3 objects in moving Field of View]

For the objects I have an estimate of big they are supposed to be. Though that estimate is not really exact (between 0.3 and 0.7 of a region of interest). 
The output is a 500x500 pixel matrice, in which the objects bounding boxes and the labels for the objects should be added.

If the object moves at full speed through the field of view I get 5 samples at maximum, before it's out again. I'm not sure if this is enough to do proper tracking.

Comment: Take a look at Kalman filtering since your measurements have error